# Can I save the temporary environment of a function in R?

Tags: r, function

I'm currently writing a rather large function for a specific plot. I would like to keep all the objects created by the function for bugfixing reasons, but my web search so far has been unsuccessful.

A quick visualization. Suppose

```
fun <- function(x) {
  y <- x+1
  z <- y^2
  z*4
}

fun(2)
[1] 36
```

For this simple case, I would like to keep y and z in an accessible environment to be able to comprehend which results certain stages of my function produce.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like this? `fun <- function(x) { y <- x+1 ; z <- y^2 ; return(list(y,z,z*4)) }`

Comment: For debugging use `browser()` this funcions puts you into an interactive session wherever it is called. You can explore and even change the variables in the funcitions scope there.

Comment: Agree with @snaut. Which objects do you want to save for bugfixing reasons? Temporary or persistent? Which values of those objects? Final or intermediate? You are better off launching a debugging session. Modern R IDEs like RStudio make this very simple.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `browser()` option. Returning all objects in a list would be pretty time-consuming, as the function is really big. Gonna try using `browser()` or assigning certain objects to .GlobalEnv. Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return the objects in a list or assign the variables inside the function with

```
assign("x", x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answer from @user116, there is a special operator for achieving what you want.

It's a shortcut to the assignment function **using the `<<-` operator**. Check out `help("<<-")` for more info. But basically, you could "save" `y` and `z` in the global environment by doing this:

```
# Make sure that these do not exist first.
stopifnot( all( !exists("y"), !exists("z")))

fun <- function(x) {
  y <<- x+1
  z <<- y^2
  z*4
}

fun(2)

# Verify y and z exist now.
stopifnot( all( exists("y"), exists("z")))
y
z
```

There's a lot to learn about environments, which might be helpful for writing long functions, etc., so this is just the tip of the iceberg.