# How to save a value that's generated and used in an r function to keep it in the environment?

Tags: r

I have a function (Save.R) that creates a few variables and saves them in a table for further use.

I also have a matrix in my main code that I want to replace some of its cells with a FileName that is generated in the function.

Question: how do I keep FileName and save it to my environment?
*I'm new to R please explain in simple words.

I have tried to input my matrix as an input to Save.R and replace cells as it generates the FileName(s) but it does not work.

```
for (i in 1:435){
  X = subset(NGAW2_Flatfile_Vertical_5percentdamping, grepl(Uniques[i,1], 
             NGAW2_Flatfile_Vertical_5percentdamping$`Station ID  No.`))
  if (nrow(X)==1){
    # Match[count,] = subset(NGAW2_Flatfile_Vertical_5percentdamping, grepl(Uniques[i,1], NGAW2_Flatfile_Vertical_5percentdamping$`Station ID  No.`))
    Match[count,] = X[1,]

    H1 = substring(X[1,113], 10,15)
    H2 = substring(X[1,114], 10,15)
    V = substring(X[1,115], 10,15)
    St.ID = substring(X[1,9], 1, 7)
    Save(H1, H2, V, Match)

    count=count+1
  }
}

Save <- function(H1, H2, V){

  H1 = paste(H1, ".DAT", sep = "")
  data = read.delim(H1, sep = "", header = FALSE)
  When1 = substring(data[2,1],2,11)
  FileName1 = paste("20", When1, "_", St.ID, "_", "H1", sep = "" )

}
```

Comment: `<<-` is also a very contentious operator, where many (including me) strongly discourage its use in lieu of a more functional paradigm where side-effect is avoided.

Comment: check out the `assign` function. You can do things like `assign("newVarName", variable, envir = .GlobalEnv)` so it doesn't matter how nested your functions get

Comment: Please post all of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I save the temporary environment of a function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128443/can-i-save-the-temporary-environment-of-a-function-in-r)

Comment: Simply `FileName1` on a new line before you close the function would also work.